# Rename file as per fixed patter in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, rename, ksh

I have these files in mydir:

```
APPLE_STORE_iphone12.csv
APPLE_STORE_iphonex.csv
APPLE_STORE_ipad.csv
APPLE_STORE_imac.csv
```

Need to rename the files after a matching pattern "APPLE_STORE_".

Required O/P

```
APPLE_STORE_NY_iphone12_20210107140443.csv
APPLE_STORE_NY_iphonex_20210107140443.csv
APPLE_STORE_NY_ipad_20210107140443.csv
APPLE_STORE_NY_imac_20210107140443.csv
```

Here is what I tried:

```
filelist=/mydir/APPLE_STORE_*.csv

dtstamp=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

location='NY'

for file in ${filelist}
do

        filebase=${file%.csv}
        mv ${file} ${filebase}_${location}_${dtstamp}.csv
done
```

This is giving me name like APPLE_STORE_imac_NY_20210107140443.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another (maybe not so elegant) way is to first explicitly divide the filename in its parts using awk with separator "_" and then build it up again as needed. Your script could then look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
filelist=./APPLE_STORE_*.csv
dtstamp=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
location='NY'

for file in ${filelist}
do

  filebase=${file%.csv}
  part1=`echo ${filebase} | awk -v FS="_" '{print $1}'`
  part2=`echo ${filebase} | awk -v FS="_" '{print $2}'`
  part3=`echo ${filebase} | awk -v FS="_" '{print $3}'`
  mv ${file} ${part1}_${part2}_${location}_${part3}_${dtstamp}.csv

done
```

I tested it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are so close.

```bash
destfile="$(echo $file | sed -e 's/^APPLE_STORE/APPLE_STORE_${location}/' -e 's/\.csv$/${dtstamp}.csv/')"`
mv "$file" "$destfile"
```

...or something like that.